# How to get different context for different tests in one class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the following test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestClass.Config.class)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class TestClass {
    @Autowired
    private MyClass myClass;

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        myClass.run();   // this is mock
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        myClass.run();   // Need real context
    }

    @Configuration
    static class Config {

        @Bean
        MyClass myClass() {
            return mock(MyClass.class);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I replace test context to the real context in different test methods?

Comment: IMHO For your own sake use different classes

Comment: Thanks to all for the help I implemented it in the different classes.

Answer (score 0):

It is another layer test. It rule of thumb to keep them separated.
You should create separate test class with real context. It should be named TestClassIntegrationTest(for example). Real context tests can be really slow and sametimes they should be ran as last check before commit.

Answer (score 0):

`@ContextConfiguration` annotation can be defined only on Classes. Here is its definition:

```
 @Target(ElementType.TYPE)
 ...
 public @interface ContextConfiguration {...}
```

Hence its impossible to define different contexts for different tests in the same class.

In addition, Spring Application context loads before the actual test method runs so you can't really influence it from within the method.

So the best would be indeed running two different test cases (different files)